# Spring LDAP - Creation of LdapTemplate in standalone java program - Using Spring LDAP as CDI Resource

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-ldap

I am trying to construct a LdapTemplate object of using spring data.

```
 public class LDAPTemplate {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            LdapContextSource lcs = new LdapContextSource();
            lcs.setUrl("ldap://localhost:389/");
            lcs.setUserDn("cn=Manager, dc=example, dc=com");
            lcs.setPassword("secret1");
            lcs.setDirObjectFactory(DefaultDirObjectFactory.class);
            LdapTemplate ldap = new LdapTemplate(lcs);
            ldap.lookup("cn=aaa");

        }

    }
```

I wanted to know is that the right way to instantiate ldap template object. Because when I perform a lookup, it throws NPE.

I am trying to use LDAP Spring in CDI context without using spring at all. If you have pointers on that would be nice. Does Spring LDAP is dependent on spring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`LdapContextSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/AbstractContextSource.html) is `InitializingBean` so you need to call `afterPropertiesSet`...

And the JavaDoc:

> When using implementations of this class outside of a Spring Context
>   it is necessary to call afterPropertiesSet() when all properties are
>   set, in order to finish up initialization.

Answer (score 4):

**Correct Code**

```
public class LDAPTemplate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LdapContextSource lcs = new LdapContextSource();
        lcs.setUrl("ldap://localhost:389/");
        lcs.setUserDn("cn=Manager, dc=example, dc=com");
        lcs.setPassword("secret1");
        lcs.setDirObjectFactory(DefaultDirObjectFactory.class);
        lcs.afterPropertiesSet();
        LdapTemplate ldap = new LdapTemplate(lcs);
        ldap.lookup("cn=aaa");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: To Use Spring LDAP in CDI conte without using Spring IoC**

1. Create a resource producer for LDAP template.

   ```
   public class Resources {
   private LdapTemplate template;

   @Produces
   //It is a custom qualifier
   @CustomeLDAPTemplate
   public LdapTemplate getTemplate() {
       LdapContextSource lcs = new LdapContextSource();
       lcs.setUrl("ldap://localhost:389/");
       lcs.setUserDn("cn=Manager, dc=example, dc=com");
       lcs.setPassword("secret1");
       lcs.setDirObjectFactory(DefaultDirObjectFactory.class);
       lcs.afterPropertiesSet();
       template = new LdapTemplate(lcs);
       return template;
   }

   public void setTemplate(LdapTemplate template) {
       this.template = template;
    }
   }
   ```
2. Create a custom qualifier - To say I want tempate object of LdapTemplate  and CustomeLDAPTemplate type

   ```
   @Qualifier  
   @Retention(RUNTIME)  
   @Target({TYPE,CONSTRUCTOR, METHOD, FIELD})  
   public @interface CustomeLDAPTemplate {}
   ```
3. Implementation on - I used a JAX-WS class to verify.

   ```
   @Path("/users")
   @RequestScoped
   public class UserResource {

       @Inject
       @CustomeLDAPTemplate
       private LdapTemplate template;

       @POST
       @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
       public Response createUser(InputStream is){
           User user = readStream(is);
           System.out.println("LDAP Look up " + template.lookup("cn=aaa,ou=Org1, dc=example, dc=com").toString());
           uRepo.save(user);
           return Response.created(URI.create("/users/" + user.getUser_id())).build();
       }   
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * contextSource
 * @return 
 */
@Bean
public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl(properties.getProperty("ldap.url"));
    contextSource.setBase(properties.getProperty("ldap.base.dn"));
    contextSource.setUserDn(properties.getProperty("ldap.principal"));
    contextSource.setPassword(properties.getProperty("ldap.password"));
    contextSource.setReferral("ignore");
    return contextSource;
}

/**
 * Create Ldap Templelate Instance
 * @return 
 */
@Bean
public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate();
    try {
        ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("error while creating LDap Template", e);
    }
    return ldapTemplate;
}

/**
 * this Method check if the username and password are valid
 * then return either true if exists and false if not
 * @param username
 * @param password
 * @return
 */
public Boolean authenticateUser(final String username, final String password) {
    boolean auth = false;
    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
    try {
        ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
        log.info("ldapTemplate-->" + ldapTemplate);

        final AndFilter filter = new AndFilter().and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", OBJECT_CLASS)).and(new EqualsFilter(NETWORK_USER_ENTITY, username));
        auth = ldapTemplate.authenticate(BASE_DN, filter.encode(), password);
        log.info("is Valid user :" + auth);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("error while creating LDap Template", e);
    }
    return auth;
}
```