# Get an object's name by resolving its GUID via LDAP in ActiveDirecotry in Java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, guid

There's a GUID of a printer device with this format in a nxlog generated log:

`119d0d80-699d-4e81-8e4e-5477e22ac1b3`

I'd like to get the device name by resolving its GUID via LDAP. However, the nearest field I encountered is `objectGUID` in [ldapsearch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch) response, which is apparently a `Base64` encoded value:

`objectGUID:: fuAW6fefLke30d46TDTUWA==`

---

Are these two above GUIDs relative in any way? (In other words, Should I search the first GUID among `objectGUID` fields in `AD` after format conversion?

How may I get the object name by using `LDAP` query in java?

It wasn't possible to achieve that via `getAttribute()` method and below code:

```
        //Create the initial directory context
        LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null);

        //Bind directly using the string form of the GUID
        String strGUID = "<GUID="+guid+">";

        //Specify the attributes to return
        String returnedAtts[]={"distinguishedName"};

        Attributes attr = ctx.getAttributes(strGUID,returnedAtts);

        //print out the retrieved attributes
        if(attr!=null)
            distinguishedName = attr.get("distinguishedName").get().toString();
        System.out.println("distinguishedName: " + distinguishedName);

        ctx.close();
```

and I got `NameNotFoundException`:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310021B, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    ''
```

Is the format of name (`<GUID="+guid+">`) correct? (I don't see any sign of the usage of this format in the repsponse output of `ldapsearch`)

Comment: You have to execute a search.

Comment: I'm not a Java developer, but from what I can find, `LdapContext` doesn't seem to let you do that. You can try using [`LdapTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html) if you can ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22436351/1202807) and use `"LDAP://mydomain.com/<GUID=" + guid + ">"` as the LDAP path.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks. One problem here is I wasn't able to decode the `objectGUID` that got from _ldapsearch_ response. (It gets converted successfully from Base64 to Byte, but the conversion from byte to string gives a gibberish string, not any close to a GUID string format). Ergo I can't confirm this field is the one I should look for a GUID (such `119d0d80-699d-4e81-8e4e-5477e22ac1b3`). So I'm not sure what should be targeted for the search.

Answer (score 1):

The [ObjectGuid](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ObjectGUID) as used in Microsoft Active Directory is a little strange compared to must GUIDs.

You have to contend with a few aspects including [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness/)

I did find a reference to some [Java Code](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1157698).